# Не работает форма на wordpress, что делать?

Tags: php, wordpress

[image] Вот код

```
` <?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; if ($name == '') {unset($name);}}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {unset($email);}}
if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {$subject = $_POST['subject']; if ($subject == '') {unset($subject);}}
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {$body = $_POST['body']; if ($body == '') {unset($body);}}
if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($subject) && isset($body)){
$address = "pups22297@gmail.com";
$message = "Имя: $name \nE-mail: $email \nТема: $subject \nТекст: $body";
$send = mail ($address,$subject,$message,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
if ($send == 'true')
{echo "Спасибо, ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!";}
else {echo "Ошибка, сообщение не отправлено!";}
}
else
{
echo "Вы заполнили не все поля, необходимо вернуться назад!";
}
?>
```

Не хочу использовать плагины. Поэтому сделал свою форму отправки, но она не отправляет письмо, в чём дело?`

```
<section>
<div class="container"> <!-- container --> 
    <div class="row"> <!-- row --> 
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-6"> <!-- col --> 
            <h2 class="contact--h">Есть вопросы?</h2>
            <p class="contact--p">Если у вас есть вопросы, вы хотите получить консультацию или есть какие-то предложения, то напишите нам сообщение, в котором можете всё подробно изложить и объяснить. Мы с вами свяжемся по телефону или напишем на почту, которую вы укажете в сообщени.</p>
         </div> <!-- /col --> 
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-6 text-center"> <!-- col --> 
       <form action="/wp-content/themes/pro-rbt.ru/myForm.php" method="POST"> <!-- form -->
        <div class="form-row"> <!-- form-row -->
          <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"> <!-- form-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control d-block w-100" id="Name" name="name" placeholder=" Имя" required=""> <!-- input -->
          </div> <!-- /form-group -->
          <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"> <!-- form-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control d-block w-100" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="8 (__) __-_-__" required="">  <!-- input -->
            </div> <!-- /form-group -->  
        </div> <!-- /form-row -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control d-block w-100" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Электронная почта" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">  <!-- form-group -->  
            <textarea class="form-control d-block w-100 htextearea" id="Textarea" name="message" placeholder="Ваше сообщение" required></textarea> <!-- input -->  
          </div>  <!-- /form-group -->
         <button type="submit" class="btn form_btn">Отправить сообщение</button> <!-- button -->
      </form> <!-- /form -->

         </div> <!-- /col --> 
    </div> <!-- /row -->  
</div>  <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: код формы приведите и где у вас расположен приведенный код? Вы для начала пробелы перед <?php вытрите, чтобы файл начинался не с пробелов

Comment: В папке темы расположен

Comment: а как вы данные пытаетесь отправить? аяксом? Если да, то событие тоже приведите в вопросе

Comment: Нет, без аякса. Почему меня пренаправляет на страницу архив?

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос приведите примеры кода которые я прошу. На какой странице форма расположена ваша?

Comment: Привёл, на всех страницах сайта есть форма.

Comment: Она у вас так и не будет отправляться - доступа к файлам темы из публички нет. Сделайте аяксовую отправку или вынесите файл в корень(что не очень хорошо).
Посмотрите тут https://inprocess.by/blog/otpravka-formy-ajax-v-wordpress/

Comment: Не помогло с ajax